# Matrix from Excel to Python

Tags: python, excel, numpy, openpyxl

I'm writing a Python program that will import a square matrix from an Excel sheet and do some NumPy work with it. So far it looks like OpenPyXl is the best way to transfer the data from an XLSX file to the Python environment, but it's not clear the best way to turn that data from a tuple of tuples* of cell references into an array of the actual values that are in the Excel sheet.
*created by calling `sheet_ranges = wb['Sheet1']` and then `mat = sheet_ranges['A1:IQ251']`

Of course I could check the size of the tuple, write a nested `for` loop, check every element of each tuple within the tuple, and fill up an array.

But is there really no better way?

Comment: I would recommend looking into the pandas library. Here's a link to the pandas documentation which provides a 10-minute how-to guide for using the package. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Comment: You can use the `values` property so you don't have to extract these manually.

Comment: @CharlieClark, I tried using `values` but as far as I could tell it was telling me that I could only take one scalar with it at a time - not a matrix.

Comment: See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html#converting-a-worksheet-to-a-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

As commented above, the ideal solution is to use a pandas dataframe. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_excel("name_of_my_excel_file.xlsx")

print(dataframe)
```

Just `pip install pandas` and then run the code above, only replacing `name_of_my_excel_file` with the full path to your Excel file. Then you can proceed with Pandas functions to deeply analyse your data, for example. See docs at [here](https://pandas.pydata.org)!

Comment: Thank you! This looks very close to what I want, except one thing. It's omitting some rows and columns, I'm almost sure it's because they contain only zeros. Is there a way to tell it to distinguish between zeros and empty cells?

Comment: Could you send me an example of your tables?

Comment: I want to copy [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/avraf4vniy66bat/SPM_FITS.xlsx?dl=0) into Python, as an array, with no missing rows or columns. If you look at the linked Excel file, the top two rows and the leftmost column are all zeros, and missing from the dataframe created by `dataframe = pd.read_excel('SPM_FITS.xlsx')`

Comment: Correction: The missing rows and columns are not necessarily all zeros. There are all-zero rows and columns remaining, but still some rows and columns missing. It's more complex now than I thought.